# Dialog window that depends on the number of buttons defined by viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, binding

I have viewmodel similar to this:

```
public class MyDialogViewModel
{
    public MyButtonViewModel[] Buttons{ get; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public MyDialogViewModel(InputObject input)
    {
        Title= input.Title;
        Message = input.Message;
        Buttons= input.Buttons;
    }
}

public class MyButtonViewModel
{
    public MyButtonViewModel(ICommand command, string text)
    {
        Command = command;
        Text = text;
    }

    public ICommand Command { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
}
```

I can't change this viewmodel.

Now I need to make window that act as a dialog window with custom set of buttons represented by `MyButtonViewModel[]`. `MyButtonViewModel[]` can have varied number of objects.

How could I make my window so it would have a size appropriate for the size of `MyButtonViewModel[]` and will have set of buttons bound to every 
presented `MyButtonViewModel`?

To make it clear - if `MyButtonViewModel[]` have 2 elements - window should have 2 buttons. 3 buttons for 3 elements and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` as suggested by @Babbillumpa. It will create an element for each item in its `ItemsSource`.

But you also need to define how you want a `MyButtonViewModel` to be represented on the screen. You do this by defining an `ItemTemplate`. This is where you create the actual `Button` element that binds to your `Text` and `Command` source properties:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons, Mode=OneTime}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    Command="{Binding Command, Mode=OneTime}"
                    Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You have my UpVote!

Comment: @Babbillumpa: And you have mine :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ItemsControl` :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

You could also set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` in order auto fit the Window.